# Can't load 64 bit DLL in 64 bit java program

Tags: java, dll, 64-bit, java-native-interface, 32-bit

== EDITED==

Guess that has something to do with the Lib. I'm using [MsmqJava](http://msmqjava.codeplex.com/) and it looks like if I call Queue.sendBytes() the error happens, but if I call Queue.send(Message) it doesn't. Thanks for everything.

== EDITED ==

I have a DLL compiled for 64bit (I've checked it with dumpbin).

I am trying to run a Java program that make use of that library with no success. `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` dumps 64. I have used that library with other Java programs with success so I know that's not from it. It must be the way I am compiling or instantiating the JVM. Anyone knows what might be going on? The error is the following:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006da48ad7, pid=3208, tid=4868
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x258ad7]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# hs_err_pid3208.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

I noticed that for some reason, really don't know if it's normal, the JVM is trying to load a bunch of windows 32 bit libraries:

```
Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x000000000042e000     C:\Windows\system32\java.exe
0x0000000077420000 - 0x00000000775c9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077200000 - 0x000000007731f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd4e0000 - 0x000007fefd54c000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x000007fefe7e0000 - 0x000007fefe8bb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007feff090000 - 0x000007feff12f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007feff710000 - 0x000007feff72f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007feff130000 - 0x000007feff25d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000000006d7f0000 - 0x000000006def4000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x0000000077320000 - 0x000000007741a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefd950000 - 0x000007fefd9b7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
```

Comment: I see you are using AMD.Did you try in an Intel 64 bit?

Comment: On a 64 bit system, all files in `system32` are 64 bit. The 32 bit files are in `SysWOW64`, so the DLL is not attempting to load 32 bit libraries. Blame MS for keeping the naming (including 32 in foldernames and filenames) even though the files are 64 bit...

Comment: Thanks. I cannot try it with other computer since I don't have any other here with me. The strangest thing is that I've another application that loads just fine but this one doesn't... I's really getting on my nerves...

Comment: I would try Java 6 update 30 to check isn't not a bug which has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The error EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) is caused by a code bug the the DLL.  The fact that your getting the access violation means the DLL is being loaded.  Your symptom of Queue.send() working and Queue.sendBytes() failing further says there is a bug in the DLL.